# Adding multiple SUMIF's

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to add 5 columns (5 different sheets), only taking numbers that are greater than 0 in a specific column. I also have another cell which will be used to do the same but with numbers less than 0. My issue is that my formula gives me a really wacky number which isn't even close to what I'm looking for.

Here's what I have, it should be pretty self explanatory on it's own, but if more information is needed let me know:

```
=SUMIF(Monday!E24:E38,">0")+SUMIF(Tuesday!E24:E38,">0")+SUMIF(Wednesday!E24:E38,">0")+SUMIF(Thursday!E24:E38,">0")+SUMIF(Friday!E24:E38,">0")
```

This is also pretty messy as it is, so any suggestions on making something a bit cleaner would be helpful too.

Thank you in advance to anyone that can help!

Comment: use sumifs then

Comment: it would be a lot more readable if you created a named range (CTRL-F3) called say DAYS which comprises your 5 ranges and then you could just have a formula =SUMIF(DAYS,">0")

Comment: @RobSedgwick I tried that but that gives me a #VALUE! error. The range is called ManuInOut and covers =Monday:Friday!$F$22:$F$36. The formula I made is =SUMIF(ManuInOut,"<0").

Comment: @stupideye the range is wrong, it should be comma-delimited, e.g. =Monday!$F$22:$F$36,Tuesday!$F$22:$F$36

Comment: @RobSedgwick Still getting the same error. My range is now "=Monday!$F$22:$F$36,Tuesday!$F$22:$F$36,Wednesday!$F$22:$F$36,Thursday!$F$22:$F$36,Friday!$F$22:$F$36"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you cannot use SUMIF across multiple sheets. The solution is to use a combination of SUMIF, INDIRECT and SUMPRODUCT as shown here:

https://exceljet.net/formula/3d-sumif-for-multiple-worksheets

[image: https://exceljet.net/sites/default/files/styles/function_screen/public/images/formulas/3D%20SUMIF%20for%20multiple%20sheets.png?itok=YWNYB5jC]

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you for the help Rob. Much appreciated.